# StackExchange.Redis is timing out since connecting to Azure Redis

Tags: stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

> Exception Message: Timeout performing GET allBots,  inst: 1, mgr:
>   Inactive, err: never, queue: 7, qu: 0, qs: 7, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in:
>   65536, ar: 0,  IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=1,Max=1000),  WORKER:
>   (Busy=0,Free=2047,Min=1,Max=2047)
>
> Timeout performing GET stock_by_symbol_leg.to,  inst: 1, mgr:
>   Inactive, err: never, queue: 13, qu: 0, qs: 13, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0,
>   in: 0, ar: 0,  IOCP: (Busy=3,Free=997,Min=1,Max=1000),  WORKER:
>   (Busy=3,Free=2044,Min=1,Max=2047)
>
> Timeout performing GET stock_by_symbol_aapl,  inst: 1, mgr: Inactive,
>   err: never, queue: 13, qu: 0, qs: 13, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar:
>   0,  IOCP: (Busy=3,Free=997,Min=1,Max=1000),  WORKER:
>   (Busy=3,Free=2044,Min=1,Max=2047)
>
> Timeout performing GET
>   portefoliosBotById_ec030000-0001-1200-0000-000000000000,  inst: 1,
>   mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 13, qu: 0, qs: 13, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq:
>   0, in: 0, ar: 0,  IOCP: (Busy=3,Free=997,Min=1,Max=1000),  WORKER:
>   (Busy=3,Free=2044,Min=1,Max=2047)

I am using StackExchange.Redis version 1.1.603 and the smallest Azure instance available. I am getting a lot of GET/SET timeout error. I do not have this issue when working locally with a Redis server on my box which make me lean that the problem in on Azure. The information stored in Redis is about 2kb to 10kb.

On Azure portal, I see my number of connection under 20, memory usage around 130meg, cpu usage under 35%, and the Redis server load is always below 13%. I do not see any indication of problem from the portal.

Any idea where I can get more information to work that problem out?

### Edit

Since my initial post, I improved few settings.

1) I passed from C0 to C1 instance of Azure Redis.

2) I changed the connection string to have 15 sec timeout. Here is how it looks:

boursexxxxxxx.windows.net:6380,password=xxxxxxxx,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,connectRetry=5, connectTimeout=15000, synctimeout=15000"

3) I created a pool of 10 Lazy Loading ConnectionMultiplex that I am rotating on each call.

```
private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>[] lazyConnection;

//In the static constructor of my cache :

lock (lockPookRoundRobin)
{
                lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>[POOL_SIZE];
                var connectionStringCache = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheConnectionString"];
                for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++)
                {
                    lazyConnection[i] = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionStringCache));
                }
}
```

4) I reduced the value of many cache. Depending of the object serialized I have :

4.1) 1.25ko (5%)

4.2) 0.154ko (5%)

4.3) 26ko (20%)

4.4) 700ko (here we need to work on, but it's limited to < 100 entries)

4.5) 5ko (30%)

4.6) 66ko (40%)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your ThreadPool settings need to be adjusted as [described here](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/e65411214030f0d823cb#file-threadpool-md).

You may also want to review these articles as well as they will help you be aware of common issues that people run into when using Redis:

- https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f#file-redis-bestpractices-md
- https://gist.github.com/JonCole/db0e90bedeb3fc4823c2#file-diagnoserediserrors-clientside-md

Comment: Nice source of information. I have most of them. I'll increase Azure from the Basic to a standard size (even if it's very expensive). I'll try to have a pool of ConnectionMultiplexer. I'll write back my result soon.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that are reading that post. I did few things:

- If you are using Entity Framework, be sure to limit the number of
  deepness you go during serialization.
- Compress the serialized string.
- Use C1 instead of C0.
- Add a lot of telemetry to find the frequency of
  setting and getting from the cache, optimize heavy scenario.
- Cache the Redis cache with a Memory Cache on IIS. I did something very
  small, but was releasing the pressure for case with heavy data need.

Being on the cloud, with Redis not on the same server as the webservice add a significant overhead.